# ASP.Net MVC4 HandleError not rendering view specified

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, exception

I have one controller Action that has a very different view than the rest of my application and I want any exceptions thrown by that Action to show a different error page than the rest of my app.

I have modified the HandleError attribute but it is NOT loading the error page at all when an exception occurs.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [HandleError(View = "UPI_Error")]
    public ActionResult ParticipantUpdate1(Participant part)
    {
        try
        {
            mps.ParticipantUpdate(LogonTicket, ParticipantID, part);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string x = ex.Message;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Any ideas?

***UPDATE***

OK, modified to this:

```
[HttpPost]
[HandleError(View = "UPI_Error", ExceptionType = typeof(ArgumentException))]
public ActionResult ParticipantUpdateSuccess(Participant part)
{
    // Copy the new stuff into the original ParticipantInfo before updating essentially "merging"
    Participant OrigPart = CopyParticipant(part);
    try
    {
        string result = mps.ParticipantUpdate(LogonTicket, ParticipantID, OrigPart);
        if (result != "Update Success")
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(result);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(e.Message);
    }
    return View();
}
```

But, it STILL doesn't load the UPI_Error page. The ParticipantUpdate call throws this exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1 was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=ORA-12899: value too large for column "CLI"."CLI_MAIN_ZIP" (actual: 21, maximum: 11)
```

In the article at this link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/exception-or-error-handling-in-Asp-Net-mvc-using-handleerror/

It says that `HandleError` is not able to catch an exception raised outside of controllers. Since the exception occurs in my web service and is propagated to my application, could that be part of the problem?

But I am throwing a new exception when I catch the one from the web service and it still shows the YSOD vs. my custom error page.

***UPDATE***

OK, I have decided to go a different route. I catch the exception, copy the exception object to TempData and then call my custom view. However, I, for some reason, can't change the Layout in the view. It comes over with a null reference exception. Any more ideas?

```
[HttpPost]
[HandleError(View = "UPI_Error")]
public ActionResult ParticipantUpdateSuccess(Participant part)
{
    bool error = false;
    // Copy the new stuff into the original ParticipantInfo before updating essentially "merging"
    Participant OrigPart = CopyParticipant(part);
    try
    {
        string result = mps.ParticipantUpdate(LogonTicket, ParticipantID, OrigPart);
        if (result != "Update Success")
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(result);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        error = true; //  throw new ArgumentException(e.Message);
        TempData["exception"] =  ex;
    }
    if (!error)
    {
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("UPIError"); 
    }
}

public ActionResult UPIError()
{
    ViewBag.Exception = TempData["exception"];
    return View();
}
```

Exception thrown:

Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  StackTrace:
       at ASP._Page_Views_Home_UPIError_cshtml.Execute() in ...\Views\Home\UPIError.cshtml:line 4

Here is line 4 in my View (YES, the view exists in the Shared folder):

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_UPILayout.cshtml";
```

Had a View naming issue but got that worked out. Now, I still get the Null Reference exception but the view is there and named correctly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your error handler, you specify that you want to use your custom error view for exceptions of type `ArgumentException`, whereas the currently raised exception is `System.ServiceModel.FaultException`. Have you tried to catch a higher Exception class like :

```
[HandleError(View = "UPI_Error", ExceptionType = typeof(Exception))]
```

Or more specifically to test your case :

```
[HandleError(View = "UPI_Error", ExceptionType = typeof(System.ServiceModel.FaultException))]
```

Comment: Tried both with same result

Answer (score -1):

For custom error pages to work, the `web.config` should be configured correctly. In `<system.web>` this setting must be present:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error"/>
```

A custom view must be present in the Views folder of the controller or in the Shared folder.

The next action (on a `HomeController`) demonstrates this. If you call this action with id set to 0, it will throw an `ArgumentException` and thus display the custom `ContactError` view. If you call it with id set to 1, it will display the default `Error` view. If you call it with an id greater than 1 it will display the Contact view

```
[HandleError(View = "ContactError", ExceptionType = typeof(ArgumentException))]
public ActionResult Contact(int id)
{
    if (id == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    if (id == 1)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I already have customErrors set to On. Is the defaultRedirect required for custom error pages?

Comment: No, it's not. Your current code doesn't throw an exception though, because it is caught by the `catch` block.

Comment: Ok, I removed the `try..catch` and it shows the YOSOD instead of my custom error page. I tried adding the defaultRedirect in my customErrors like this `<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.cshtml"/>` and got this URL `Error.cshtml?aspxerrorpath=/Home/ParticipantUpdateSuccess`

Comment: I'm thinking that the problem here is that the ParticipantUpdate call function in my web service is why it doesn't do it. If there is an exception in the service, it throws the exception I noted above.  Anyone else think so?

Comment: I have updated the code but am still not getting the Custom Error page to show. Any more ideas?

Comment: Do you have any more ideas as to what I may try? Please see my updated code above.

Answer (score -1):

This should work fine as long as you do the below things

`customErrors` turned on in the web.config file

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" />
</system.web>
```

and you have decorated your ation method with  the `HandleError` action filter and specified the view name.

```
[HandleError(View="MyError")]
public ActionResult ErrorTest()
{       
    throw new ArgumentException("Just-Throw-An-Exception");
    return View();
}
```

And you have the `MyError.cshtml` razor view present inside inside your `~/Views/{YourCurrentControllerName}` or `~/Views/Shared/` directory.

Comment: Did you not read the entire post, here? It is 100% apparently clear that I have all of those conditions met. But it still doesn't work. It looks like you are just trying to inch your way in to hopefully collect on the bounty that I do not believe should be awarded for the ***NON-WORKING*** responses I've gotten.

Comment: I tried this in a new project and worked fine. So i am assuming there is something else in your project which is causing it to not work.

Answer (score -1):

You are catching the exception but not throwing a new one in catch clouse. You should not catch the exception or you should throw an exception to let application show error page.

İf you catch an exception in catch try catch block your code countinues from catch scope and does nor throw any error.

You need an error thrown and not catched by try catch block ro get error pages.

Comment: Did you not see the `throw new ArgumentException(e.Message);` in the catch?

Comment: This answer was before your update. Stop putting -1 to every single answer that does not work for you. We are trying to give you some ideas.